# Changing from 1.654924e+03 to 1654.924 when writing to file in Matlab

Tags: file, matlab, file-io

I am outputing data on a file for later usage from another application and the numbers are stored in the form of 1.654924e+03 while I want the file to include numbers in the form of 1654.924000

My source code for appending data into the file is

```
d='D:\Dropbox\data\gyro.txt';
fid=fopen(d,'at');
fprintf(fid,'%d',sumg(1));
fprintf(fid,'\n');
fprintf(fid,'%d',sumg(2));
fprintf(fid,'\n');
```

I am using Matlab2013a

EDIT**
as it seems my question was not good enough.
I want the number to be printed correctly (without the e+03) and have 3 zeros after the last non zero decimal point. Also the numbers are not standard. This was just an example.
Sorry for the confusion my original question has created

Comment: I didn't know MATLAB would do this to anyone. I would consider this a bug.

Comment: @s.bandara To be fair, providing a floating-point number to an integer formatter is a bit questionable.

Comment: What is the actual question? How is 1.654924e+03 related to 1654924000 – they're completely different numbers?

Comment: I apologise for that, it was a mistype, I missed the .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a fixed decimal output using %f. To do so with no trailing decimal points, use %.0f. So:

```
>> x = 1.654924e+03;
>> fprintf("%.0f\n", x);
1655
```

Of course, that's not the value you wanted, but the value you gave and the value you wanted aren't equal. But we can adjust for that:

```
>> fprintf('%.0f\n',x*10^6);
1654924000
```

Comment: but the value is not standard, this was just an example, I need a more standard way tha x*10^6.

Comment: @JohnDemetriou: What exactly do you want? `1.654924e+03` is `1654.924`, how do you get to `1654924000`

Comment: I apologise for that, I missed the , It was a mistype

Answer (score 0):

Knowing your last update: You are looking for this:

```
fprintf("%.6f\n", x);
```

Described [here](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html#inputarg_formatSpec)

Comment: Well I guess my question is not good enough. The digits are not standard. I just want three zeros after the last non zero digit

Comment: This is not really possible and a very strage format, most double values have high number of non-zero digits because of the double precision, try `fprintf("%.30f\n", x);` to make some of them visible.

Comment: I read your question, but what should happen with doubles like 1/3? This would result in `0.333333333333333314829616256247390992939472198486328125000`

Comment: The data is from EEG measurements, numbers like those would not exist, plus 1/3 is always 0.333333333333333333333, it never changes

Comment: Not in double arithmetic, there it changes.

Comment: hmm, true, but that does not occur in my situation